# Kubernetes: The proxy server is refusing connections

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have started with kubernetes and followed this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/) to get the response as they mentioned. I followed the exact steps but when I am trying to open the port I get the following error:

[image]

How to solve this issue? I have tried by adding the IP address and port in the Browser proxy.

Can anyone help me on this?

Here is the service image: [my service image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7e37.png)

List of pods: [Kubectl Pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGKIi.png)

List of kubectl deployments:[Deployment List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1fXT.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using the baremetal(simple laptop) to deploy your service.

If you have look at `my-service` it is in `pending` state and it is of type `LoadBalancer`. The type load balance is supported only for the cloud providers like aws,azure and google cloud. Hence you are not able to access anything.

I will suggest you to follow this tutorial [here](https://blog.tekspace.io/exposing-pod-as-a-nodeport-service/) which allow you to deploy nginx as a pod and deploy a service around that and export that service as nodeport (without load balancer) to be able to access from outside.

Comment: Thanks for your response Prafull i will try this and will let you know.